# Apache Cassandra install causes dependency failure

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, cassandra

I am trying to install Cassandra on ubuntu machine,

I have set entries in /etc/apt/sources.list file

deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 10x main
deb-src http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 10x main

but when i run apt-get install Cassandra after update i am getting following error message.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cassandra : Depends: jsvc (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libcommons-daemon-java (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libjna-java but it is not going to be installed
 syslinux-common : Breaks: syslinux (< 2:4.05+dfsg-2) but 4.02-8 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have also tried -f option, but it won't worked for me.

what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Packages are searched in a list of repositories enlisted in special file /etc/apt/sources.list, which can be [edited](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197564/how-do-i-add-a-line-to-my-etc-apt-sources-list) a few ways. So, the first thing you should try when encounter such messages is to find a repository which can be added to make specific packages findable.

In your case, I don't in which repo these can be found. Moreover, such information can get irrelevant quite soon.

If you fail to find repo containing all packages you need (or you just don't want to add new repo for some reasons), you can google them, download them manually and install via `dpkg -i package.deb`. For instance, `libjna-java` can be downloaded [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/base/libjna-java).